Switching Yarn Version
I have yarn 3.6.4 currently enabled on my mac.
I'm trying to change that to 1.22.22 for a certain project I'm working. I'm using the below.
yarn set version 1.22.22

I get this response
➤ YN0000: Retrieving https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v1.22.22/yarn-1.22.22.js
➤ YN0000: Saving the new release in .yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.22.cjs
➤ YN0000: Done in 1s 769ms

However when I check yarn -v, I'm still getting 3.6.4.
Anyone any idea why?

Hi, please can you run the command 'which yarn' to see which yarn executable is being used and let me know.
